# How to get created by and modified by values from sharepoint list using angular http get

Tags: angular, sharepoint

I am getting response like Created date and modified date but created by and modified by is missing.

```
this.http.get(this.baseurl + "_api/web/lists/getByTitle('mylist')/items?$select ID,Created,CreatedBy,Modified,ModifiedBy", { headers: { Accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose' } });
```

My sharepoint list also contains same column name like ID,Created,CreatedBy,Modified,ModifiedBy without any space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research and testing, the **created by** field is **Author**, **modified by** is **Editor**, You can use the following code to get created by and modified by:

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('xxxx')/items?$select=ID,Created,Modified,Editor/Title,Author/Title&$expand=Editor/Id,Author/Id
```